# Call history.back() without triggering 'popstate'

Tags: javascript, html, history, browser-history, popstate

Is there a way to call `window.history.back();` without triggering  `this.getWindow().on('popstate', this.handleBrowserButtons.bind(this));`?

Answer (score 0):

No, `window.history.back` and `window.history.go` would always trigger the popstate event.

In fact, that's the only time the event is actually triggering so you could probably remove the popstate event handler altogether and use something else if you don't want this happening on back/forward navigation.

Comment: To provide some further explanation: I would like to reload the page 'onpopstate' EXCEPT I call window.history.back and window.history.go in a removeModal() function.

Comment: the onpopstate event would ONLY be called when you do window.history.back and window.history.go. When do you expect the onpopstate event to fire?

Comment: When the user goes back/forward in his browser

Comment: Ah I see, unfortunately it is not possible to avoid the onpopstate out of the box, but for example you could add a global variable to window just before you call back and go in your code and then check the variable in the popstate event. Some thing like window.didNavigateFromCode = true, and then check that boolean in the popstate event, if it is true, don't do any processing.

Answer (score 0):

As history.back and history.go always call a registered onpopstate event you could make the onpopstate event the main way of closing the modal. I did this when I was doing something similar and it worked well.

To keep this backward compatible with browsers that don't support pushstate you can check for support and call closeModal directly when there is no support.

So the close modal button code would be like this:

```
if (history.pushState) {
    // Your popstate event handler will be called, which calls closeModal()
    history.back();
}
else {
    // No popstate event handler registered, so call closeModal() directly
    closeModal();
}
```